# javafx jar will not run, no main class found

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, jar

I know this has been asked many times but none of the solutions worked for me. I'm using gradle to build a runnable jar for a javafx app. I'm using the Java 8 jdk and jre. When I open the jar with 7zip I see that it has my classpath included in it.

Here are my files:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' version '2.4.9'
    id 'application'
}

application {
    mainClass = 'sample.Main'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes (
                'Main-Class': 'sample.Main',
                "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '))
    }
}

launch4j {
    outfile = 'MortgageCalculator.exe'
    mainClassName = 'sample.Main'
}
```

**Main.java**

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Maximum House Bid Calculator");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Project Structure**

[image]

**Contents of the jar from build/libs**

[image]
[image]

**Output when trying to run the jar**

[image]

**Output of using `gradle run` from command line**

```
D:\dev\repos\java\MortageBidCalculator>gradle run

> Task :run FAILED
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 4s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

I think the `gradle run` error is just because it's not finding the `fxml` file, so I'm pretty sure that's unrelated to the no main class found error, but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a jar file from the command line, you need the `-jar` option:

```
java -jar MortgageBidCalculator.jar
```

The other issue, which is causing the null pointer exception, is that the FXML file is not in the jar file.

Create a `resources` folder under `src/main`, a `sample` subfolder, and move `sample.fxml` to `src/main/resources/sample`.

Comment: But how do I make it executable with double-click? Also I changed the location of the fxml into a resources folder that gradle recognizes, so now it's in the jar but I still get the null pointer error.

Comment: @abg You put it in the `sample` subfolder, like I suggested, correct? So the FXML file is in the same folder as the `Main` class? It should be executable via double-click if you have Java 8 as the default JRE on the machine. But obviously nothing will happen if it's just throwing the exception.

Comment: For some reason it's ending up in the top level directory of the jar. I'm not sure how to change that.

Comment: @abg Again, you're putting it in a `sample` subfolder of `resources`, correct? Update your question with the new layout and screenshots of the jar file (or just show the contents using `jar -tf MortgageBidCalculator.jar` from the command line.

Comment: No it was just in resources. Putting it in sample worked. Thanks!